# Where are the default wallpapers in the upgrade of Android to 4.4.2?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a Xolo Q1010 and i upgraded its android version to 4.4.2 Kitkat. After upgrading, i realized that the default wallpapers of Xolo had vanished. I could only now put live wallpapers. Pls tell how to get back those wallpapers?

Comment: Did you install an official update? Chances are they are wiped out, but you could always Google Xolo Q1010 wallpapers and find a few images that way?

Answer (score 0):

Wallpapers often comes bundled with the application (inside the APK file), and usually, those apps are launcher apps. It appears that previously your default as well as stock launcher had those wallpapers. Now that the update has been installed, that launcher has been replaced or updated (in any case the APK is new) too, so your best bet is to find the launcher APK which comes with your previous version of Android.

You can locate the APK inside the stock ROM (if you've one, or download it).